# printing a value from a string variable

Tags: java, variables, netbeans

I used the code below. It uses a string variable

> String[] parts = cmdAndArgs.split("/");

and another variable

> String cmd = parts[0];

```
String response = "okayh";
    String[] parts = cmdAndArgs.split("/");
    String cmd = parts[0];
if (cmd.equals("analogWrite"))
            {
           if(parts[1].equals("Speaker"))//addedline
               {
                int value=3;
               arduino.analogWrite(value,    Integer.parseInt(parts[2]));//addedline
}

response = "";
    System.out.print ("" +cmdAndArgs.split("/"));
```

I wanted to view the values in the variable `cmdAndArgs`, so i did

```
response = "";
System.out.print ("" +cmdAndArgs.split("/"));
```

But it gave the following output

> [Ljava.lang.String;@964130

I cannot understand what the output is or how I can view the `String` passed in that variable?

Comment: Because it is an array of string you have to do a foreach to printing the strings in the array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Split returns an array. You are just printing the array object where you have to print the array contents.

Probably you want

```
System.out.print (Arrays.toString(cmdAndArgs.split("/")));
```

or you can iterate over the array to print each string in it.

Comment: thk u tht prints a string. String[] parts = cmdAndArgs.split("/");  here parts is a variable which is split. i want to know the string values tht is in parts [0] , parts[1] and parts[2] is that the same procedure ?

Comment: System.out.print(Arrays.toString(parts[0]));  is this correct

Comment: No, This is correct `System.out.print (cmdAndArgs.split("/")[0]);`

Comment: Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.ClassFormatError: Method "<error>" in class a4/A4 has illegal signature "(Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/System$out$println;"   I got this error

Answer (score 0):

For printing the array you have to do a foreach like this

```
for (String cmd : cmdAndArgs){
System.our.println (cmd);
}
```